# When do I need new io_service?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I am recently working a lot with `boost::asio` and mulling over its documentation which is not of much help in some matters. I cannot wrap my head around a few questions which are associated with one another. The most important is this - when would I need to create my own `io_service` implementation (and how to do it properly)?

Let's take an example. I want to handle message bus communication with `asio`. The library that provides the API returns to me an opaque pointer to connection which allows me to only write requests and read responses. So far, so good. All these operations can be handled via `boost::asio::post` operation within any `io_context` really. Do I need a new `io_service` here to handle this? Or an `io_object` is sufficient here? Where to draw the line?

It is possible I don't really understand what these concepts (`io_service` and `io_object`) represent and this is the root cause of all the fuss

Comment: What is `io_object`?

Comment: @sehe AFAIK sockets are examples of `io_object`s

Comment: They are, it's just that you were referring to them with an absoluteness (using `identifier` markup) that made me think you were referring to something else.